# Edit a confluence page title to add its ID?

Tags: macros, confluence

I'm trying to add a unique ID to page titles in confluence.

I managed to add a user macro which uses jQuery to add the page ID & a string prefix to the title;

```
## @param _prefix:title=Prefix|type=string|required=true|desc=Prefix for the page ID

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("document").ready(function() {
  if ("${param_prefix}" != "${_prefix}")
    jQuery('#title-text a').prepend('${param_prefix}', '$content.getIdAsString()', ' ');
});
</script>
```

But I want this to actually edit the title, not just get added at runtime. It needs to be consistent throughout, allowing that ID to be a search term & appear in all menus etc.

I can't find anything which suggests this is even possible but it must be, surely!?

Answer (score 0):

$content.setTitle("newtitle") should work. BUT! you will have to make sure that this only happens once, otherwise your title will get repeatedly prepended with your text every time this macro is rendered. I guess you might check if the title starts with your prefix already. And then you might want to add handling of changing the prefix.

See http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF35/Guide+to+User+Macro+Templates#GuidetoUserMacroTemplates-OtherObjectsAvailabletoyourMacro for more details.

That being said, this seems like a pretty kludgey way of solving whatever problem you have. I would suggest reconsidering if this is really what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, its not a nice way of doing it but the problem is we will have hundreds/thousands of pages, possibly with similar titles so need a unique ID on each to link all content in confluence and elsewhere. So adding the page ID to the title was my ideal - I started to wonder if this can be done in the layout/styles settings but I don't know much about these yet.

Comment: I'm not thinking about the part with the page id, that seems like a workable way of making unique page titles. I'm thinking more about doing this through a macro. That would mean manually adding this macro to every page. The easiest way might actually be to shut confluence off and make a MySQL script to run though all of your pages.

Comment: By the way, can't you just link with the id instead? Why do you need to add it to the title?

Comment: Adding it to the title was a visual thing. The ID will also be added to screens in the product which each page represents & should hopefully make it easier for testers to find the confluence content they need. I hadn't considered a DB approach - we'll have to have a look at that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the actual Confluence page ID or the page tiny link rather than generating an ID of your own.  Both of these are static.

On any Confluence page, type "k" to see a hyperlink.  You might be surprised to see it also contains a tiny link.  Atlassian confirms that the tiny link stays the same, even if you move and rename the page (https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-27049). This is a consistent way to reference the same page with a fixed URL.  Another way is to use the Confluence built in PageID.

Confluence Knowledge Base: How to get Confluence page ID
https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-get-confluence-page-id-648380445.html

- Ensure that the current user has permissions to View and Edit the
  page Navigate to a specific page
- Go to Edit Mode by clicking Edit button or press 'e' key

The URL in the address bar will change once you enter Edit Mode 
Page ID will be displayed as the parameter in the    URL e.g.: When entering Edit Mode, the URL will change to http://my.domain.com/pages/editpage.action?pageId=1540132 
In the example above, **1540132** is the Page ID.

To get the page ID with a macro:
ContentEntityObject contentEntityObject = conversionContext.getEntity();
System.out.println("pageId : " + contentEntityObject.getId());

To change a title: content.setTitle("newtitle"). 
Remember, check if title contains the page id before setting title = title + page ID.